# About Padding the synchronization structures

Tags: c, linux, pointers

I have read about Padding to the structure  in the following webpage :

http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/2/c/d/3/9/25602-17689_w_spinlock.pdf

as it describe: it suggest the following statements to do padding to sync structure :

```
struct syn_str { int s_variable; };
void *p = malloc ( sizeof (struct syn_str) + 127 );
syn_str * align_p = (syn_str *)( (((int) p) + 127) & -128 );
```

What comes to my mind is that , it could be done much easier like :

```
 struct syn_str { int s_variable; char padx[124] ; }  in 32-bit OS
```

or

```
 struct syn_str { int s_variable; char padx[120] ; }  in 64-bit OS
```

since all it like to do is to fill a structure full with 128 bytes , or something I miss in my way for this ?

Update:

Thanks for all kind informations !!  after post question, I have 
googled for "align structure"   and look like "posix_memalign"  seems to be quite right function call to use ...

Comment: That's for alignment, and padding with 124 or 120 isn't necessarily good enough, it depends on the alignment of `malloc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two reasons for this:

1. To make sure the structure doesn't cross over a cache boundary and take up two cache lines, thus requiring two fetches and two invalidations per access
2. To make sure there's only one structure per cache line, and prevent false sharing.

Alignment to the beginning of a cache line provides both.  Padding the structure to the same size as a cache line provides neither.

Imagine, if you will, the following structure on a system with 4-byte int and 8-byte OS heap alignment and 128-byte cache lines (very common):

```
struct bare
{
    int x, y, z, u, v, w;
};
```

Merely adding padding, as in:

```
struct padded
{
    int x, y, z, u, v, w;
    char pad[128 - 6 * sizeof (int)]; // 104
};
```

does not prevent the object from being allocated at address 112, where `x, y, z, u` fall into one page and `v, w` into a second one.  So the first goal is violated.  And another object could be allocated at address 248, with `x, y` in the same cache line as the previous object's `v, w`.  So the second goal is violated.

However,

```
char* block = malloc(sizeof (bare) + 127);
bare* p = reinterpret_cast<bare*>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(block + 127) & ~127);
```

Makes both guarantees without difficulty, because each object will start at the beginning of some cache line.

Answer (score 0):

Nooo, sizeof operator for an integer variable still returns 4 in 64bit systems. Bytesize is implementation defined.

Comment: It varies by implementation.  But the important thing is that the correct padding is `(alignment-1)`, not `(alignment - sizeof struct)`